# Specify list length range in Python Cerberus

Tags: python, cerberus

I need to set the minimum and maximum length of a list between 2 - 5. Is there a way to specify this in Python Cerberus. Here's what I have currently but this allows lists of all sizes:

```
  {
    "levels": {
        "type": "list",
        "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": True,
            "nullable": False,
            "empty": False,
        },
        "required": True,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [minlength/maxlength](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#minlength-maxlength) rules in your schema for your list -

```
{
    "levels": {
        "type": "list",
        "minlength": 2,
        "maxlength": 5,
        "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": True,
            "nullable": False,
            "empty": False,
        },
        "required": True,
    },
}
```

This will make sure that length of `levels` list is between 2-5.